# Content loaded into a div using javascript appears in a small square

Tags: javascript, html

Ive been coding a site for a project a friend and I are working on. After spending more time than I should have researching how to use javascript to make site links load into a "content" div ive gotten it to work, que second problem: The content loads but sits within a small square inside the "content" div I was wondering how to resize the content being displayed within the div below is my page code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="content-type">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<title>Breezies Blog</title>
<style>
.header {
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('file:///C:/Users/Zenga/Desktop/egoblog/bg21.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 187px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: static;
  }
a {
    color: white;
  }
ul {
    padding: 5px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    position: relative;
    top: 142px;
    border-radius: 10px;

  }
li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
body {
     background-image: url('file:///c:Users/Zenga/Desktop/egoblog/fullbg.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: black;
   }
section {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    height: 600px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
 </style>
 </head>
<body>
<div class="header">
  <nav id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="load_home()">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="load_cast()">Cast Of Characters</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="load_hist()">History of Ego</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="load_create()">Meet the Creators</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<br>
<section>
<div class="content" id="content"> </div>
</section>
<script>
function load_home(){
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" style="overflow: hidden" data="main.html"></object>';
  }
function load_cast(){
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" style="overflow: hidden" data="cast.html"></object>';
  }
function load_hist(){
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="hist.html"></object>';
  }
function load_create(){
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="create.html"></object>';
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `second problem` ?? where's the first one?

Comment: the first problem was getting the script to work in the first place, which i solved, but now the problem is the content being displayed is in about a 100x100 box instead of the div which is defined as 1000(max) x 600

Comment: Oddly this code also has issues displaying the body's background image in FF and in IE but not chrome, so far everything works in chrome, aside from my current sizing issue

Answer (score 0):

you're not giving the content div a size so it just goes auto, give it a min-width and min-height

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: how doesn't it ??? his question is  why is the box coming out tiny, my answer is that there's no size on it so like I said,  add the min sizes. You got a better answer than put it here ...

Comment: @Billy I think what Liarez is trying to say is you need to pad it out a bit more. Could you possibly provide a code example to help the OP and anyone else who comes across this answer? That way you are contributing to the quality of the answers and helping the SO community.

Comment: the div dimensions are defined under 'section' in the style tag. even when directly applying those to the div instead of the containing 'section' I get the same results, also when applying a min value to the height and width

Comment: SOLVED! Billy was half right, I had to define the object size using width and height tags, not min-width and min-height tags. All four nav links work with no over flow and unnecessary scroll bars. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction guys!